# Why euicc manager get NO_SUCH_ELEMENT aka errcode 3?

Tags: android, javacard, apdu, e-sim, euiccmanager

**Problems：**
I got status 3 was error NO_SUCH_ELEMENT when using euicc manager sending apdu.

**What I did：**
I sorted an euicc chip （ST33G1M2）and pluggin into my phone， and trying to port the euicc manager (com.google.android.euicc, premission granted) to my phone. Now debugging and this error occurs （NO_SUCH_ELEMENT）

**Needed：**
I cannot find how to call lower level or hardware. could anyone helps about hal/hardware of Android system？ or did you have meet this error.

**I traceback them at aosp codes (the file provided below)**,but I didn’t see anything about hardware. Does it async to another proccess?

PhoneInterfaceManager.java:

```
                case CMD_OPEN_CHANNEL:

                request = (MainThreadRequest) msg.obj;

                uiccPort = getUiccPortFromRequest(request);

                IccLogicalChannelRequest openChannelRequest =

                        (IccLogicalChannelRequest) request.argument;

                if (uiccPort == null) {

                    loge("iccOpenLogicalChannel: No UICC");

                    request.result = new IccOpenLogicalChannelResponse(-1,

                            IccOpenLogicalChannelResponse.STATUS_MISSING_RESOURCE, null);

                    notifyRequester(request);

                } else {

                    onCompleted = obtainMessage(EVENT_OPEN_CHANNEL_DONE, request);

                    uiccPort.iccOpenLogicalChannel(openChannelRequest.aid,

                            openChannelRequest.p2, onCompleted);

                }

                break;

            case EVENT_OPEN_CHANNEL_DONE:

                ar = (AsyncResult) msg.obj;

                request = (MainThreadRequest) ar.userObj;

                IccOpenLogicalChannelResponse openChannelResp;

                if (ar.exception == null && ar.result != null) {

                    int[] result = (int[]) ar.result;

                    int channelId = result[0];

                    byte[] selectResponse = null;

                    if (result.length > 1) {

                        selectResponse = new byte[result.length - 1];

                        for (int i = 1; i < result.length; ++i) {

                            selectResponse[i - 1] = (byte) result[i];

                        }

                    }

                    openChannelResp = new IccOpenLogicalChannelResponse(channelId,

                            IccOpenLogicalChannelResponse.STATUS_NO_ERROR, selectResponse);

                    uiccPort = getUiccPortFromRequest(request);

                    if (uiccPort == null) {

                        loge("EVENT_OPEN_CHANNEL_DONE: UiccPort is null");

                    } else {

                        IccLogicalChannelRequest channelRequest =

                                (IccLogicalChannelRequest) request.argument;

                        channelRequest.channel = channelId;

                        uiccPort.onLogicalChannelOpened(channelRequest);

                    }

                } else {

                    if (ar.result == null) {

                        loge("iccOpenLogicalChannel: Empty response");

                    }

                    if (ar.exception != null) {

                        loge("iccOpenLogicalChannel: Exception: " + ar.exception);

                    }

                    int errorCode = IccOpenLogicalChannelResponse.STATUS_UNKNOWN_ERROR;

                    if (ar.exception instanceof CommandException) {

                        CommandException.Error error =

                                ((CommandException) (ar.exception)).getCommandError();

                        if (error == CommandException.Error.MISSING_RESOURCE) {

                            errorCode = IccOpenLogicalChannelResponse.STATUS_MISSING_RESOURCE;

                        } else if (error == CommandException.Error.NO_SUCH_ELEMENT) {

                            errorCode = IccOpenLogicalChannelResponse.STATUS_NO_SUCH_ELEMENT;

                        }

                    }

                    openChannelResp = new IccOpenLogicalChannelResponse(

                            IccOpenLogicalChannelResponse.INVALID_CHANNEL, errorCode, null);

                }

                request.result = openChannelResp;

                notifyRequester(request);

                break;
```

****logs below：****

```
 2023-10-14 13:22:14.534  3860-3860  EuiccCardController     com.android.phone                    E  getEuiccChallenge callback onException: 

                                                                                                com.android.internal.telephony.uicc.euicc.EuiccCardException: Cannot send APDU.

                                                                                                    at com.android.internal.telephony.uicc.euicc.EuiccPort.lambda$sendApdu$50(EuiccPort.java:1159)

                                                                                                    at com.android.internal.telephony.uicc.euicc.EuiccPort.$r8$lambda$8x9Mw_LfktrBXDaDFYF0Xl8vpps(Unknown Source:0)

                                                                                                    at com.android.internal.telephony.uicc.euicc.EuiccPort$$ExternalSyntheticLambda52.handleException(Unknown Source:2)

                                                                                                    at com.android.internal.telephony.uicc.euicc.EuiccPort$1.onException(EuiccPort.java:1224)

                                                                                                    at com.android.internal.telephony.uicc.euicc.apdu.ApduSender$1.onResult(ApduSender.java:138)

                                                                                                    at com.android.internal.telephony.uicc.euicc.apdu.ApduSender$1.onResult(ApduSender.java:127)

                                                                                                    at com.android.internal.telephony.uicc.euicc.async.AsyncMessageInvocation.handleMessage(AsyncMessageInvocation.java:57)

                                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)

                                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:238)

                                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:357)

                                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8088)

                                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

                                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)

                                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:957)

                                                                                                Caused by: com.android.internal.telephony.uicc.euicc.apdu.ApduException: Failed to open logical channel opened for AID: A0000005591010FFFFFFFF8900000100, with status: 3 (apduStatus=0)

                                                                                                    at com.android.internal.telephony.uicc.euicc.apdu.ApduSender$1.onResult(ApduSender.java:138) 

                                                                                                    at com.android.internal.telephony.uicc.euicc.apdu.ApduSender$1.onResult(ApduSender.java:127) 

                                                                                                    at com.android.internal.telephony.uicc.euicc.async.AsyncMessageInvocation.handleMessage(AsyncMessageInvocation.java:57) 

                                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 

                                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:238) 

                                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:357) 

                                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8088) 

                                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 

                                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548) 

                                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:957) 

2023-10-14 13:22:18.904  3860-3860  EuiccCardController     com.android.phone                    E  getEuiccChallenge callback onException: 

                                                                                                com.android.internal.telephony.uicc.euicc.EuiccCardException: Cannot send APDU.

                                                                                                    at com.android.internal.telephony.uicc.euicc.EuiccPort.lambda$sendApdu$50(EuiccPort.java:1159)

                                                                                                    at com.android.internal.telephony.uicc.euicc.EuiccPort.$r8$lambda$8x9Mw_LfktrBXDaDFYF0Xl8vpps(Unknown Source:0)

                                                                                                    at com.android.internal.telephony.uicc.euicc.EuiccPort$$ExternalSyntheticLambda52.handleException(Unknown Source:2)

                                                                                                    at com.android.internal.telephony.uicc.euicc.EuiccPort$1.onException(EuiccPort.java:1224)

                                                                                                    at com.android.internal.telephony.uicc.euicc.apdu.ApduSender$1.onResult(ApduSender.java:138)

                                                                                                    at com.android.internal.telephony.uicc.euicc.apdu.ApduSender$1.onResult(ApduSender.java:127)

                                                                                                    at com.android.internal.telephony.uicc.euicc.async.AsyncMessageInvocation.handleMessage(AsyncMessageInvocation.java:57)

                                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)

                                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:238)

                                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:357)

                                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8088)

                                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

                                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)

                                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:957)

                                                                                                Caused by: com.android.internal.telephony.uicc.euicc.apdu.ApduException: Failed to open logical channel opened for AID: A0000005591010FFFFFFFF8900000100, with status: 3 (apduStatus=0)

                                                                                                    at com.android.internal.telephony.uicc.euicc.apdu.ApduSender$1.onResult(ApduSender.java:138) 

                                                                                                    at com.android.internal.telephony.uicc.euicc.apdu.ApduSender$1.onResult(ApduSender.java:127) 

                                                                                                    at com.android.internal.telephony.uicc.euicc.async.AsyncMessageInvocation.handleMessage(AsyncMessageInvocation.java:57) 

                                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 

                                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:238) 

                                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:357) 

                                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8088) 

                                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 

                                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548) 

                                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:957)
```

Comment: you may want to put some effort in formatting your question. Currently I do not  even care scrolling to see what there

Comment: Is this version better Marcin? And thank your advice.

Comment: is it? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: To be honest, I'm not an English native speaker, and that page was terrible when translate done. I can hardly know what it is. 